# can't receive the form request from my controller

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to do a simple form. The bind between the controller and the view is done. But I can't receive the form data when the user submit.

```
public function addAction()
{
    $router = $this->get('router');
    $request = $this->get('request');

    $ret = 'not set';
    $title = 'not set';

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

    $pictures = $request->files->get('pictures');
    $title = $request->request->get('title');

    $ret = $this->get('my_project_blog.post_service')
                ->create($title, $subtitle, $description, $pictures);

    }

    return $this->render('MyProjectBlogBundle:Default:add.html.twig', array('err' => $ret, 'title' => $title));
}
```

Now the add.twig.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ path('my_project_blog_add') }}" method="POST" id="contactform">

  <fieldset id="contact_form">
    <label for="title">
      <input type="text" name="title" id="name" placeholder="Enter A Title">
    </label>
    <label for="file">
      <input name="pictures[]" type='file' multiple='multiple' ></input>
    </label>

    <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-default btn-black" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>

</form>
```

The result before submit :

```
Pictures: not set.
Title: not set
```

After submit :

```
Pictures: Error pictures count == 0.
Title:
```

Comment: usually forms are [created](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) a little bit different in symfony2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any particular reason, why you are not using Symfony form component?

Not sure how it's possible, but maybe you got wrong `request` service from container. You should use [Request Stack](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack) service or add `$request` as parameter of you action. Just tested following code and everything works correctly.

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $title = $request->request->get('title');
        $files = $request->files->all();
    }
}
```

As xurshid29 mentioned in comment, symfony gives you the opportunity to define forms easier and handle response easier.

```
// In controller
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('title')
        ->add('pictures', 'file', [
            'multiple' => true, // Since symfony 2.5
        ])
        ->add('Submit', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Process data from $form->getData()
    }

    return $this->render('MyProjectBlogBundle:Default:add.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}

// In view 
{% block content %}
    {{ form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks! The second way is working well. But the first does not. I don't know why. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Your first example does not work because of the crsf token. createFormBuilder and sf2 put a token for each form. It can be disable like this $this->createFormBuilder($object, array('csrf_protection' => false))